# How can I test if a jar is an OSGi jar?

Tags: osgi

Maybe it is a silly question, but what is the best way to test if a Java Archive (jar) file is an OSGi bundle? That is, what are the minimal requirements for the jar to be fully compatible? Is it the mere presence of a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (I don't think so)? If not, what are the minimal fields that must be provided by this file?

Practically, how should I test if the jar is an OSGi jar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look for the `Bundle-SymbolicName` header in the MANIFEST.MF. This is the only mandatory header in an OSGi bundle, at least since Release 4.0 of the OSGi specification. Therefore if the `Bundle-SymbolicName` header is defined, then the JAR is an OSGi bundle. If not, then it is just a JAR.

Comment: Still valid, according to OSGi core 6.0.0 specification Ref.: 3.2.1.16

Comment: Can you be more specific as to where in the spec that it says that Bundle-SymbolicName is the only mandatory header?  I'm not able to find that in the spec, but I'm sure it probably says that. I just find it odd that Bundle-Version is not also mandatory and just wanted to see if the spec gives some insights as to why Bundle-Version isn't mandatory.

Comment: @TomRutchik Sure, it's in the OSGi Release 7 Core Specification at [section 3.2.1.18](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#i2654895). For Bundle-SymbolicName it states "this header must be set". No other header has that wording. Bundle-Version isn't mandatory because it can be inferred: if there is no explicit version, then the version is "0.0.0". Note also that Bundle-SymbolicName was not mandatory before Release 4 of OSGi; but R4 was early 2000s so those old versions are beyond obsolete.

Comment: Thanks Neil, that's exactly what I was looking for.  It wasn't making sense to me to have a bundle without a version number, but the assumed default value of 0.0.0 if that version headed is missing clears up that confusion. Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> > A bundle is a group of Java classes and additional resources equipped with a detailed manifest MANIFEST.MF file on all its contents, as well as additional services needed to give the included group of Java classes more sophisticated behaviors, to the extent of deeming the entire aggregate a component.

---

> > The OSGi spec describes the bundle as a "unit of modularization" that "is comprised of Java classes and other resources which together can provide functions to end users.".
> >
> > a bundle is a JAR file that:
> >
> > ```
> >    Contains [...] resources
> >    Contains a manifest file describing the contents of the JAR file and providing information about the bundle
> >    Can contain optional documentation in the OSGI-OPT directory of the JAR file or one of its sub-directories
> > ```
> >
> > In short, a bundle = jar + OSGI information (specified in the JAR manifest file - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF), no extra files or predefined folder layout are required.

I guess the only qualification be required is that there are a bundle of classes and that it contains a MANIFEST.MF file which contains valid OSGi headers.

Consider this [link](http://spring.io/blog/2008/02/18/creating-osgi-bundles/)
As well as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Bundles)

Answering your question, the only way to test the bundle it to check if the MANIFEST.MF file exists and contains valid headers.